# How to get Python iterators not to communicate with each other?

Tags: python, iterator

Here's a simple iterator through the characters of a string.

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s
        self._ix = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            item = self.s[self._ix]
        except IndexError:
            self._ix = 0
            raise StopIteration
        self._ix += 1
        return item

string = MyString('abcd')

iter1 = iter(string)
iter2 = iter(string)
print(next(iter1))
print(next(iter2))
```

Trying to get this iterator to function like it should. There are a few requirements. First, the `__next__` method MUST raise `StopIteration` and multiple iterators running at the same time must not interact with each other.

I accomplished objective 1, but need help on objective 2. As of right now the output is:

```
'a'
'b'
```

When it should be:

```
'a'
'a'
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say "multiple iterators", do you realize there's only one iterator being used here ? (`string`)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Why not simply do `string = 'abcd'`? Then `iter(string)` would work like you want.

Comment: @Ahmed Why do you say it's not an iterator? If it has a `__next__` method (as well as an `__iter__` method that returns itself), it's an iterator. See [the definition in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator).

Comment: @wjandrea okay, it is an iterator ... but maybe a poorly designed one that doesn't work as what other iterators are intended to do ... at least it's not the way that any iterator i have dealt with before works.

Comment: @Ahmed That's weird, because to me it's working exactly as expected. Maybe you're confusing iterators and [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)?

Comment: @wjandrea, you are totally correct, i should probably get more familiar with the difference between python iterator and iterable.

Answer (score 3):

`MyString` acts as its own iterator much like a file object

```
>>> f = open('deleteme', 'w')
>>> iter(f) is f
True
```

You use this pattern when you want all iterators to affect each other - in this case advancing through the lines of a file.

The other pattern is to use a separate class to iterate much like a list whose iterators are independent.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> iter(l) is l
False
```

To do this, move the `_ix` indexer to a separate class that references `MyString`. Have `MyString.__iter__` create an instance of the class. Now you have a separate indexer per iterator.

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s

    def __iter__(self):
        return MyStringIter(self)

class MyStringIter:

    def __init__(self, my_string):
        self._ix = 0
        self.my_string = my_string

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            item = self.my_string.s[self._ix]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        self._ix += 1
        return item

string = MyString('abcd')

iter1 = iter(string)
iter2 = iter(string)
print(next(iter1))
print(next(iter2))
```

Comment: What value is MyString providing then? All of its functionality is in MyStringIter.

Comment: @Acccumulation - In this example, `MyString` isn't doing anything more than holding `s`. If `s` is a list, then really hasn't done anything at all because lists already have iterators. I think this is just a toy example to ask the question or to learn the basics of iteration. The only use for this exact code would be for some object in `s` that is indexable but doesn't support iteration.

Comment: Why do you say "all iterators" when there's only one? (i.e. `iter(f) is f`, like you said)

Comment: @wjandrea - In this implementation, `MyString.__iter__` creates a new iterator on each call. So there are two iterators. The iterators just return themselves. These are the two normal uncontroversial ways to write iterators.

Comment: @wjandrea - oh wait, you are tying to put something into "when you want all iterators to affect each other" but clearly I am referring to the `iter1` and `iter2` of the question. They refer to the same object of course, but they are two different variables.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm talking about your first example, opening a file. You're saying, "You use **this pattern** when you want all iterators to affect each other", but there's only one iterator there. There are two references to it of course (`iter(f)` and `f`, like `iter1` and `iter2` in the question), but an iterator is a type of *object*, not a type of reference, so that's why I say there's only one.

Comment: @wjandrea - If I write `i1 = iter(foo)` then `i2 = iter(foo)`, do I have one iterator or two? We don't know because we don't know how `foo` is implemented. Its quite natural to say there are two iterators, `i1` and `i2`. Notice I said "MyString acts as its own iterator" at the top of the paragraph, introducing the idea that there is only a single underlying iterator object no matter how many iterator variables you create.

Comment: @tdelaney I think I get it: You're referring to the result of `iter(x)` as a new iterator regardless of whether it actually is. I can see how that's useful for conceptualizing it, but to me it's just confusing. **Edit**: And I'm not sure how to phrase it to both get that across and still be technically correct, so, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title asks how to get iterators, plural, to not communicate with each other, but you don't have multiple iterators, you only have one. If you want to be able to get distinct iterators from MyString, you can add a copy method:

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s
        self._ix = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            item = self.s[self._ix]
        except IndexError:
            self._ix = 0
            raise StopIteration
        self._ix += 1
        return item

    def copy(self):
        return MyString(self.s)

string = MyString('abcd')

iter1 = string.copy()
iter2 = string.copy()

print(next(iter1))
print(next(iter2))
```

Comment: But then you are iterating two different things, not having two iterators for the same thing.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm not sure what you mean. They are for "the same thing" if "thing" refers to the data. If by "the same thing", you mean the same iterator, OP doesn't want the same iterator.

Comment: @tdelaney "not having two iterators for the same thing" -- Huh? `iter1` and `iter2` are two iterators for `'abcd'`.

Comment: @wjandrea - but they are pulling whatever else is in the instance into two more instances. It may work for this toy example, but falls apart very quickly. What if `s` is changed? What if `s` is 10.000.000 integers? What if there is anything else in the class and you can't just naively implement a simple copy? This is an antipattern. It would be better for `__iter__` to return `iter(self.s)` than this. In fact, for this example, that's by far the better solution.

Comment: @tdelaney OK, I see what you're saying. Personally, I don't see the point of the toy example at all since you could just do `string = 'abcd'` in the first place then `iter(string)` would work like OP wants, but that's beside the point.

Comment: @tdelaney "What if s is changed? What if s is 10.000.000 integers?" What problems do those issues raise, and how are they addressed by your code?